# Fixed header, footer inside a flexible fixed-position container

Tags: css, css-position

What’s the cleanest way to achieve a fixed header/footer and scrollable area inside a flexible, fixed-position container? (Example: http://cl.ly/image/293F0f3D1R2B)

Assume container’s CSS is similar to:

```
#modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/2GvCM/)

I used `position: absolute;` instead of fixed though.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on this for anyone else who might need similar.

The simplest, CSS-only approach I've found is to position the scrollable area absolutely inside an absolute container, and set the `top` and `bottom` properties so it stretches to fill the available area. (For this to work, you need to know the height of the header and footer.)

Working example + demo here: http://codepen.io/stuntbox/pen/lEdpq